# Can any statement about natural numbers be written in TNT?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I was trying to understand Godel's theorem from here [Godel's First Incompleteness](http://www.felderbooks.com/papers/godel.html) theorem. I still do not completely understand the theorem, but have a broad idea about it. As the link mentions Godel's first theorem addresses statements in Typographical Number Theory ( TNT ) which are true but unprovable using the axioms. The link assumes any statement about natural numbers can be written in TNT, such as "4 is a prime", "2 is the smallest prime number" etc. But it does not prove it in general. I am not even sure what qualifies as *a statement about natural numbers*. How do I put  it mathematically what qualifies as a statement about natural numbers and how do I prove that every such statement can be written using TNT ?

 
Sorry if my question is vague or lacks correct terminology, I can improve it if suggested.

Comment: Note that TNT is _Hofstadter's_ invention, not Gödel's; Gödel himself used an entirely different axiomatization. The article you're looking at is a little sketchy in spots, but in brief it can be said that we _define_ the set of 'statements about numbers' to be the statements that can be expressed in one of these theories. (_Peano Arithmetic_ is perhaps the most canonical).  For instance, the (informal) statement that '5 is blue' is not a statement about numbers because there's no formal definition of the notion 'is blue' in such a theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of statements which are not expressible in the language of any specific theory, such as TST or Peano arithmetic (which I'm more familiar with). Any statement involving a symbol/word not in the language of the theory can't be directly expressed. Specific examples depend on the theory involved, but for a general kind of example, the sentence "$N$ is (the Godel number of) a sentence in the language $L$ which is true of the natural numbers" is *never* expressible in the language $L$ - this is Tarski's theorem on the undefinability of truth, and is a direct consequence of the diagonal lemma.

But we're not really interested in non-expressible statements most of the time. The surprise of Godel's theorem is that (for any reasonable system) there are *expressible* statements which are not decidable.

Comment: To tell specifically whether a sentence is expressible in TNT, you need a formal definition of TNT; often in expositions people will blackbox this bit, and just sweep the expressibility of every relevant sentence under the rug, but you do need to do this.